# Erro ao criar condicional php

Tags: php, laravel

Estou criando um comando em laravel(php) que busca um arquivo imagem que esta como blob no banco e salva em uma pasta, e como nem todos os usuarios possuem imagem estou querendo fazer um condicional que se o arquivo não existir ele simplesmente pula o processo porém quando coloco o usuario que nao tem foto ele não pula o processo e retorna   Trying to get property 'logo_foto' of non-object

```
 public function handle()
{
   // $field = $this->ask('Fields?');

    $id = $this->argument('numero');
    $getInfo = Parceiro::where('id', $id)->first();
    if($getInfo->logo_foto) {
        $photo = $getInfo->getRawOriginal('logo_foto');
        $format = Helper_Base64::getFileFormat($photo);
        $randonName = rand(1, 800);
        $path2 = public_path("users/logo/{$randonName}");

        if(!File::isDirectory($path2)){
            File::makeDirectory($path2, 0777, true, true);
        }

        $path =  "$path2/{$randonName}.$format";
        Partner::getLogoUrl($id, false, null, $path);
       // Partner::getLogoUrl($id);
        $getInfo->img_path = $path;
        $getInfo->save();
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método `exists` antes de chamar o método `first()`

1:

```
$id = $this->argument('numero');
$getInfo = Parceiro::where('id', $id);
if ($getInfo->exists()) {
    // info existe
    $info = $getInfo->first()
} else {
    // info nao existe
}
```

Outras posibilidades:

2:

```
$id = $this->argument('numero');
$getInfo = Parceiro::where('id', $id)->first();
if ($getInfo) {
    // info existe
} else {
    // info nao existe
}
```

3:

```
$id = $this->argument('numero');
$getInfo = Parceiro::where('id', $id)->first();
if ($getInfo->isNotEmpty()) {
    // info existe
} else {
    // info nao existe
}
```